# Excel VBA sumifs defined as string

Tags: vba, excel

How do i define a `SUMIFS` formula in VBA so it prints the actual string? I have been using the VBA method of `SUMIFS` but now the ranges in question will have their values changed after my macro has run but because of the `""` i can't use this,

```
GD as String
GD = "=SUMIFS(G:G, F:F, "=GD")"
```

And i can't use this

```
GD = Application.WorksheetFunction.SumIfs(hours, typeRange, "=GD")
```

As the output doesnt change if any value in either of the ranges does.

Any clues on how to get round this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just needed that formula printing as a string in a cell, the answer beneath nailed it. Its a huge document that does loads so explaining exactly what i needed from it would take a decade, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By doubling up the quotes around =GD

```
GD = "=SUMIFS(G:G, F:F, ""=GD"")"
```